# Show the repeating values only once and only what changes in separated list under it

Tags: javascript, arrays, oracle

A query with select distinct of multiple columns, joins and where clause is returning records like the following:

```
ID  title   Date    other field
1   text 1  01-Jan-20   another value
1   text 1  07-Mar-20   another value
1   text 1  20-Sep-20   another value
1   text 1  30-Dec-20   another value
2   text 2  02-Feb-20   something else
2   text 2  12-Mar-20   something else
2   text 2  15-May-20   something else
2   text 2  17-Jul-20   something else
```

How can I display all the repeated values once and only the dates that are changing like this:

```
1, text, another value
01-Jan-20
07-Mar-20
20-Sep-20
30-Dec-20

1, text, something else
02-Feb-20
12-Mar-20
15-May-20
17-Jul-20
```

Should I change the oracle query or do something with map, reduce on the array of the results in the language that I am using?
Any example?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What if you have two same dates or same title but different "other fields"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```js
let myObj = {};
`1   text 1  01-Jan-20   another value
1   text 1  07-Mar-20   another value
1   text 1  20-Sep-20   another value
1   text 1  30-Dec-20   another value
2   text 2  02-Feb-20   something else
2   text 2  12-Mar-20   something else
2   text 2  15-May-20   something else
2   text 2  17-Jul-20   something else`.split(/\n/)
.forEach(line => {
  let [_, num, title, date, val] = line.match(/(\d+)\s+(.*?)  (.*?)   (.*)/)
  // console.log("n",num,"t",title,"d", date, "v",val)
  if (!myObj[title]) myObj[title] = { num:num, val:val,dates:[] }
  myObj[title].dates.push(date)
})

console.log(myObj)
```